# Making a JPanel "blink" a couple of times after pressing a JButton

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

I've got a simple JPanel and JButton in a JFrame. I would like it to blink a couple of times when the button is pressed. The main issue is I've tried a couple different ways to get it do do so, using Thread.sleep(200) and a for loop for the numBlinks. However, this just "pauses" the panel while it switches the color and only shows the final result.

Thank you.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class BlinkingJPanel implements ActionListener{

    private JFrame window;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JButton button;

    private final Color BACKGROUND1 = Color.GRAY;
    private final Color BACKGROUND2 = Color.WHITE;
    private final Color BORDER_COLOR = Color.BLACK;
    private final int BORDER_SIZE = 1;

    private final int WINDOW_SIZE = 200;
    private final int PANEL_SIZE = 100;
    private final int BUTTON_SIZE = 100;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BlinkingJPanel main = new BlinkingJPanel();
    }

    public BlinkingJPanel() {
        setUpWindow();
        setUpPanel();
        setUpButton();

        window.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        window.add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }

    private void setUpWindow() {
        window = new JFrame("Blinking JPanel");

        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setBackground(BACKGROUND1);
        window.setSize(WINDOW_SIZE, WINDOW_SIZE);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void setUpPanel() {
        panel = new JPanel();

        panel.setSize(PANEL_SIZE, PANEL_SIZE);
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(BORDER_COLOR, BORDER_SIZE));
        panel.setBackground(BACKGROUND1);
        panel.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void setUpButton() {
        button = new JButton("Blink");

        button.setSize(BUTTON_SIZE, BUTTON_SIZE / 2);
        button.setActionCommand("Button1");
        button.addActionListener(this);
        button.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        switch(e.getActionCommand()) {
        case "Button1": blink(1);
            break;
        default: System.out.println("Default Case");
            break;
        }

    }

    private void blink(int numBlinks) {
        // TODO: make panel blink on it's own

        if(panel.getBackground() == BACKGROUND1) {
            panel.setBackground(BACKGROUND2);
        } else {
            panel.setBackground(BACKGROUND1);
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: You need to use javax.swing.Timer

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html Docs that @ControlAltDel referenced

Answer (score 2):

I created a solution using a Timer. Iv'e tried to keep it simple. All i did was add a timer, which takes the time you wish for it to pop when you start it (they keep popping every so milliseconds, ive set this to 300ms) and an actionlistener which i just used the class itself. When the timer pops it triggers the actionlistener which makes it blink untill the amount in BLINK_AMOUNT at the top has been reahed. Then stops the timer and resets the blink count to 0. The timer only starts when you press the button.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class BlinkingJPanel implements ActionListener{

private JFrame window;
private JPanel panel;
private JButton button;

private final Color BACKGROUND1 = Color.GRAY;
private final Color BACKGROUND2 = Color.WHITE;
private final Color BORDER_COLOR = Color.BLACK;
private final int BORDER_SIZE = 1;

private final int WINDOW_SIZE = 200;
private final int PANEL_SIZE = 100;
private final int BUTTON_SIZE = 100;

private final int BLINK_AMOUNT = 1;
private Timer blinkTimer;
private int blinkCount;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BlinkingJPanel main = new BlinkingJPanel();
}

public BlinkingJPanel() {
    setUpWindow();
    setUpPanel();
    setUpButton();

    window.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    window.add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    //Timer constructor takes pop time and action listener
    blinkTimer = new Timer(300, this);
    blinkCount = 0;

    window.setVisible(true);
}

private void setUpWindow() {
    window = new JFrame("Blinking JPanel");

    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setBackground(BACKGROUND1);
    window.setSize(WINDOW_SIZE, WINDOW_SIZE);
}

private void setUpPanel() {
    panel = new JPanel();

    panel.setSize(PANEL_SIZE, PANEL_SIZE);
    panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(BORDER_COLOR, BORDER_SIZE));
    panel.setBackground(BACKGROUND1);
    panel.setVisible(true);
}

private void setUpButton() {
    button = new JButton("Blink");

    button.setSize(BUTTON_SIZE, BUTTON_SIZE / 2);
    button.setActionCommand("Button1");
    button.addActionListener(this);
    button.setVisible(true);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource().equals(button)){
        blinkTimer.start();
    }
    else if(e.getSource() instanceof Timer){
        if(blinkCount == BLINK_AMOUNT){
            blinkCount = 0;
            blinkTimer.stop();
        }
        blink();
        blinkCount++;
    }else{
        System.out.println("Default");
    }
}

private void blink() {
    if(panel.getBackground() == BACKGROUND1) {
        panel.setBackground(BACKGROUND2);
    } else {
        panel.setBackground(BACKGROUND1);
    }

}
}
```

If any of this is confusing, feel free to ask.

As you said, thread.sleep() wont work as all swing runs on one thread, so making calling that function will make the whole thread stop running (executing code)  and then run the next part of the code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Kyal Bond, this worked. I think I understand it all. The only change I had to make was under actionPerformed(...) {...

Comment: so that it resets each time.
 
        blink();
        blinkCount++;
        if(blinkCount == BLINK_AMOUNT){
            blinkCount = 0;
            blinkTimer.stop();
        }

Comment: oh do you want continuous blinking? but if the matter is resolved please accept the answer so others know :)